# CSProj file minimal list of multiple target frameworks

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj

I have this list of TargetFrameworks in a .csproj file:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net45;net452;net462;net472;net48;netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp3.0;netcoreapp3.1;netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Do I really need all of those or can I remove some of them which are covered by .net standard?

Comment: If you don't use new features, but you have to support net45, then target net45, net461, netstandard2.0. Otherwise target net461 & netstandard2.0

Comment: Thanks, it works on .net core and .net 5, and on Windows it also works for .net framework 4.8, but not on mono. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard it should have worked (I run it with mono version 6.12) unless I misunderstood what they are saying.